# How to display news in facebook mobile app

Tags: wordpress, facebook

How to display news / articles and display card type as some news sites do in facebook mobile app?

[image]

I am developing a WordPress site .

Answer (score 1):

That’s called **Instant Articles**.

A “light-weight” article format, specifically designed for mobile - a bit similar to Google’s Accelerated Mobile Pages.

More information on how to prepare your content, how to publish it etc. can be found in the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles